# Is there a way of cutting a raster map that is displayed in the GRASS GIS Map Display?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, png, clip

I have a raster map that I generated from cropping/masking from a bigger raster map. It produced a map with only a portion of not null values. I only want to have a map that is zoomed in to the portion of not null values in order to save it into a PNG file. I only succeeded in setting the region (g.region) to the portion, but not cutting the map that only contains that portion.

Comment: You should also check the relevant wiki page: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Cropping_maps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do that with the help of MASK and r.resample (make a copy of your raster before)
This video would guide you : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tfcyxRvEJ8

Comment: Thanks! it was very helpful. Given the resulting map that I generated, can i save the map in PNG format? I tried running the r.out.png, but it failed and produced errors.

Comment: how did it fail? you may want to try r.out.gdal with the PNG driver instead, its more robust than the one-off exporters.

Comment: You can use r.out.gdal to export to PNG. But r.out.png works fine, you "just" have to write into a directory in which you have permissions to save files.